# Understanding stack frame of function call in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, stack

I am new to C/C++ and assembly lang as well.
    This could also be very basic question.
    I am trying to understand how stack frames are built and which variables(params) are pushed to stack in what order?. 
    Some search results showed that....compiler of C/C++ decides based on operations performed within a function. for e.g if the function was suppose to just increment value by 1 of the passed int param and return (similar to ++ operator)  it would put all ..the param of the function and local variable within the function in registers and perform addition ....wondering which register is used for returned/pass by value ?....how are references returned? .....difference b/w eax, ebx,ecx and edx.

Requesting for a book/blog/link or any kind of material to understand registers,stack and heap references are used/built and destroyed during function call's....and also how main function is stored?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: The C++ language says nothing about this. Compilers can do what they like. So your question should be specific about which compilers you are talking about because the answer will depend on this. You best bet for understanding might well be to write some C++ code and see what your favourite compiler actually does.

Comment: Miles too broad for SO.

Comment: What is your knowledge related to this. Are you more a computer scientist or a software developer? What is your background?

Comment: Question was also asked on programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195385/understanding-stack-frame-of-function-call-in-c-c

Answer (score 5):

Your question is borderline here. [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) could be a better place.

A good book to understand the concepts of stack etc might be Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) (it explains quite well what a stack is for Lisp). Also, [SICP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs) 
 is a good book to [read](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).

[D.Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)'s books and [MMIX](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/mmix.html) is also a good read.

Read carefully Wikipedia [Call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) page.

In theory, no call stack is needed, and some languages and implementations (e.g. old SML/NJ) did not use any stack (but allocated the call frame in the garbage collected heap). See A.Appel's old paper [Garbage Collection Can be Faster than Stack Allocation](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/45.ps) (and learn more about [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) in general).

Usually C and C++ implementations have a stack (and often use the hardware stack). Some C local variables might not have any stack location (because they have been optimized, or are kept in a register). Sometimes, the stack location of a C local variable may change (the compiler would use one call stack slot for some occurrences, and another call stack slot for other occurrences of the same local variable). And of course some temporary values may be compiled like your local variables (so stay in a register, on in one stack slot then another one, etc....). When optimizing the compiler could do weird tricks with variables.

<sup>On some old machines [IBM/360](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System/360) or I[BM z/series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_zSeries), there is no hardware stack; the stack used by the C compiler is a software convention (e.g. some register is dedicated to that usage, without specific hardware support)</sup>

Think about the execution (or interpretation) of a recursively defined function (like the good old *factorial* naively coded). Read about [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) (in general, [in computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)), [primitive recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function), [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), [denotational semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics), [stack automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_automaton), [register allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation), [tail calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), [interrupts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt), [Posix signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal), [sigaltstack(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html), [getcontext(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcontext.2.html), [longjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html)etc.... etc...

Read also books about [Computer Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture). In practice, the call stack is so important that several hardware resources (including the *stack pointer* register, often the call frame *base pointer* register, and perhaps hidden machinery e.g. cache related) are dedicated to it on common processors.

You could also look at the intermediate representations used by the GCC compiler. Then use `-fdump-tree-all` or the [GCC MELT probe](http://gcc-melt.org/index.html#probe_id). If looking at the generated assembly be sure to pass `-S -fverbose-asm` to your `gcc` command.

See also the [linux assembly howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/).

<sup>I gave a lot of links. It is difficult to answer better, because I have no idea of your background.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to understand how stack frames are built and which
>   variables(params) are pushed to stack in what order?

THis is dependent on the architecture of the processor. However, typically, the stack grows from a high address towards a lower address (if we look at memory addressses as numeric values). One stackframe is "whatever this function puts on the stack"

The "stuff" that gets put on the stack typically is:

- Return address back to the calling function.
- A frame-pointer, pointing to the stack-frame at the start of the call.
- Saved registers that need to be "preserved" for when this function returns.
- Local variables.
- Parameters to the "next" function in the call-stack.

> compiler of C/C++ decides based on operations performed within a
>   function. for e.g if the function was suppose to just increment value
>   by 1 of the passed int param and return (similar to ++ operator) it
>   would put all ... 
>   the param of the function and local variable within the function in registers
>    and perform addition ....wondering which register is used for
>   returned/pass by value ?....how are references returned?

The compiler has rules for how parameters are passed, and for regular function calls [that is, not "inlined" functions], the parameters are always passed in the same order, in the same combination of registers and stack-memory. If that wasn't the case, the compiler would have to know exactly what the function does before it could decide to pass the arguments.

Different processor architectures have different rules. x86-32 typically has one or two registers used for input parameters, and typically one register for the return values. x86-64 used up to 5 registers for passing the first five values to the function. Any further arguments are passed in registers.

Returning a reference is no different from returning any other value. The value (which in this case is the address of the object being returned). In x86-32, return values are in EAX. In x86-64, return values are in RAX. In ARM, R0 is used for the return value. In 29K, R96 is used for the return value.