# Is returning a local pointer cause undefined behaviour

Tags: c, unix

I have a doubt in the statement

> p = my_malloc(4);

my_malloc has a local pointer called p, when the function returns the address of the pointer will be deallocated. So how is it int* p in main could hold the address returned by the function. When a function returns, the address it used may or may not be used by other functions or processes. So is this below program an undefined behaviour?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void* my_malloc(size_t size){
 void *p;
 p = sbrk(0); 
 p = sbrk(size); // This will give the previous address
 //p = sbrk(0); // This will give the current address
 if(p != (void *)-1){
   printf("\n address of p : 0x%x \n",(unsigned int)p);
 }
 else{
  printf("\n Unable to allocate memory! \n");
  return NULL;
 }
 return p;
}

int main(){
 int* p;
 p = my_malloc(4);
 printf("\n address of p : 0x%x \n",(unsigned int)p);
}
```

Comment: The memory allocated for local variables when you call a method is freed when you return from the method, and using pointers referring to that memory after returning is undefined behaviour. If you allocate dynamically on the heap and return a pointer to THAT, if you do that right, that is ok.

Comment: Thanks basile and perreal. I understood now why it is not an undefined behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code look ok, beware that [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) is nearly obsolete (and thread unfriendly), most malloc implementations use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) instead.

What is undefined behavior is to return the address of a local variable, like

```
void* topofstack() {
   char c;
   return &c;
}
```

and recent GCC compilers (e.g. 4.8) will make a warning, at least with `-Wall` which you always should use. Regarding call stacks see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16088155/841108) which gives a lot of useful links.

When coding some `malloc`, do also code the `free` (and try to avoid making a syscall too often, so re-use the `free`-d memory in `malloc` when possible). Look also into the source code of existing malloc free software implementations.
The [MUSL libc](http://git.musl-libc.org/) has some quite readable [malloc/](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/malloc) ...

Comment: Will also look into existing malloc free s/w implementation also. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The stack allocated, local storage in my_malloc is p (the address stored in p). You cannot return the address of p (`&p`) and use it later. However, the allocated space, which is pointed by p, will still be allocated. The address is copied before p is destroyed. This is no different than returning an integer value from a function.