# Where the value of variables are stored in C

Tags: c, linux, windows, compiler-construction

In the following code segment:

```
int func()
{
    int a=7;
    return a;
}
```

Is the code segment where the value 7 is stored in the executable? Or is it in data segment or in the code segment?  Will the answer depends on the Operating system or the compiler?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576489/where-are-constant-variables-stored-in-c

Comment: It depends. The compiler will sometimes store the constant in the code and load it into a register on function entry or it may just generate a `move constant 5 into register` instruction (i.e. the constant is stored in the instruction itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each executable format has some sections. One of them is `text`, contains the assembly - binary code. One of them is `heap` where `malloc`-ed data is found and on is `stack` where local variables are stored. There are several others but it doesn't matter now. The above three are common everywhere.

Now, local data like your `a` resides on the stack. In the executable file, the value is stored in the `text` section.

I've added a `main` to your code (returning 0), compiled with `-g` then did `objdump -CDgS a.out` and searched for `0x424242` (I've replaced your `7` with a value with lesser chance of randomly occurring in code).

```
00000000004004ec <func>:
int func()
{
  4004ec:       55                      push   %rbp
  4004ed:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
        int a=0x42424242;
  4004f0:       c7 45 fc 42 42 42 42    movl   $0x42424242,-0x4(%rbp)
        return a;
  4004f7:       8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
}
  4004fa:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004fb:       c3                      retq
```

As you see, `c7 45 fc 42 42 42 42` means that the value is stored in the generated file. Indeed, this is the case when looking at the binary via `xxd`:

```
$ xxd a.out | grep 4242
00004f0: c745 fc42 4242 428b 45fc 5dc3 5548 89e5  .E.BBBB.E.].UH..
```

You can recognize the above assembly line in the `xxd` snippet.

Comment: Yes, I agreed. And I would like to know where the value 5 in stored in the executable?

Comment: So the value 7 is stored in the code segment and use it as a immediate value. Am I right?

Comment: Yup. It is used as an immediate in this example.

Comment: Is there any change if we build a non optimized executable.

Comment: The above is for non-optimized case. The same is if you optimize the code.

Answer (score 2):

Since `a` is implicitly `auto` (i.e. is not `extern` or `static`) it is stored in the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) frame.

In fact, the compiler may optimize that: probably, in your case, when optimizing, it will stay in a register (or be constant propagated and constant folded): no need to allocate a call stack slot for your `a`

This is of course compiler, target platform, and operating system dependent. For the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, understand the Gimple internal representation (thru `-fdump-tree-all`, or using the [MELT probe](http://gcc-melt.org/index.html#probe_id)) and look at the generated assembler code (use `-fverbose-asm -S -O`)

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16088155/841108) which gives a lot of references.

---

GCC 4.8 on Linux/x86-64 compiles (with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O`) your function into:

```
   .globl   func
   .type    func, @function
func:
.LFB0:
   .cfi_startproc
   movl $7, %eax    #,
   ret
   .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
   .size    func, .-func
```

So you see that in your particular case no additional space is used for `7`, it is directly stored in`%eax` which is the register (defined in the ABI conventions) to hold its returned result.

<sup>The value `7` is stored in the machine code, inside the `movl` machine instruction. When `func` is executed, that 7 is loaded into register `%eax` containing the returned result of `func`.</sup>

Comment: Yes the variable a has memory in stack and I would like to know where the value 5 in stored in the executable?

Comment: The value `7` is stored in the code, inside the `movl` machine instruction. When `func` is executed, that `7` is loaded into register `%eax` containing the returned result of `func`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the example code, variable "a" goes in call stack, place to store local variables along with function call information like program counter, return addr etc